# Help understanding what the subordinate clause modifies in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, subordinate-clauses

> If the special committee for political reform at the Assembly
>   disagrees on the proposal, which calls for cooperation to hammer out a
>   final map, it is put to a vote at a plenary session.

I'm not sure what 'which calls for cooperation to hammer out a final map' modifies in this sentence. Is it the special committee or the Assembly? It depends on the context or can you determine it by just grammar or syntax?

Comment: In a case like this ("The X does Y, which Z")  I can't think of a context in which the "which" *wouldn't* refer to the last thing.  "The dog eats the biscuit, which is big and red" - the biscuit is big and red, not the dog.  In fact, anything else looks very wrong.  "The company makes a new product, which is 100 years old"?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it modifies the proposal that to be discussed at the assembly by the special committee.

Comment: The subjective of verb "calls for" can be the proposal? I thought people usually call for something.

Comment: that proposal's purpose is to urge cooperation to hammer out a final map.

Comment: I think @sotondolphin is right.

Comment: How did you come to your conclusion? Did you determine it by context or syntax? I'm not saying you're wrong - I just think this would be a better answer if it explained why you think that's the correct answer.